# ArcGIS and SqlServer.Types: Does feature.Shape.SpatialReference.FactoryCode == srid?

Tags: arcobjects, well-known-text, ogc, srid

I created a test implementation of the [ESRI Geometry to WKT recipe](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/20251/4968) provided by @SagebrushGIS. It seems to work great, but I'm wondering if the `SRID` value expected by `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` (specifically `SqlGeometry.STGeomFromWKB`) corresponds directly to `feature.Shape.SpatialReference.FactoryCode`?

I stumbled across [this thread](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/14436-Control-SRID-through-SDE) in the ArcGIS forums where user zroberthu says (not so difinitively) that the two are equal. And when I debug this line (my feature class is projected to NAD_1983_StatePlane_Missouri_Central_FIPS_2402_Feet):

```
int srid = feature.Shape.SpatialReference.FactoryCode;
// I get srid = 102697
```

Next, if I go to [SpatialReference.org](http://www.spatialreference.org/) and search by my ESRI projection name, it takes me [here](http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102697/), and I see the value `102697` most everywhere I expect to find it. However, if I select [the PostGIS insert statement](http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102697/postgis/), it shows `srid` is `9102697`, and then an "`auth_srid`" field corresponds to `102697`.

So my questions are these:

1) At the end of the day, does the SRID even matter if I'm not performing spatial operations on two different getdatasets? (Presently, I just want a simple way to expose a feature's WKT in the ArcMap UI.)

2) Can I difinitively say an ArcGIS feature's Shape.SpatialReference.FactoryCode corresponds directly to the SRID expected by SqlServer.Types and/or OGC-compliant utilities?

I can apply the SRID using other techniques, but if this is true it is handy! Thanks so much. /E