# How do you generate WKT from a graphic drawn on a map?

Tags: postgis, well-known-text, st-geometry, sql-server-spatial

All,

In order to do some quick analysis using SQL spatial, I'd like to generate spatial objects using the STGeomFromText / ST_GeomFromText function.

With point data, I can do this by geocoding an address and using desktop GIS to give me the X/Y, which I then turn into a point using a syntax like this:

```
declare @xyPoint geometry;
set @xyPoint = geometry::STGeomFromText('Point(3175288.989  1711307.592)', 2232);
```

*(This will create a temporary point geometry at the X,Y coordinates above in the 2232 (CO State Plane Central coordinate system)... I can then use the temporary point to drive distance calculations, etc.)*

**My question**: is there a way to do something similar with a polygon: maybe draw a graphic in a desktop GIS map (ArcMap, QGIS, etc.), get the WKT from that graphic, which I can then use in a query to create a polygon object using the STGeomFromText function?

Basically, this is the opposite of the [Quick Draw plugin](https://github.com/geo-data/qgis-quick-draw) for QGIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a rough, buggy ArcMap AddIn that I regularly use for diagnostics: [WKQuery](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1156285/util/WKQuery.esriAddIn)

It's a 10.0 AddIn, but I use it 10.1 and 10.2 with no trouble (well, the same amount of trouble that I have in 10.0).

But the first 3 buttons will let you draw on the map and dump the WKT to a text box in a dockable window (last button in the toolbar):
[image]

Again, it's buggy and I'm in between textbox controls (because couldn't work out a clean way to use the Scintilla component in an AddIn).

And some of the credit for WKT piece goes to [blah238](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/53096/31) because I swapped out the WKT conversion to [**DnrGps_Wkt**](https://github.com/blah238/DnrGps_Wkt).  But I also didn't read the license so I'm not sure if I'm breaking any rules--I apologize in advance if I broke the rules!

[image]

Comment: Jay - unfortunately I get an error: "No GUI components found in this Add-In. Add-In version does not match." I'm running ArcGIS 10.1 SP1... hmmm...

Comment: It was a 10.0 version but maybe I messed up the project. I just updated the AddIn version to 10.1 and recompiled. New link to a 10.1 version in this comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1156285/util/WKQuery.esriAddIn

Comment: Ahhh that's it! Works like a charm... I love how you can set your data frame SRS and the tool will report the SRS of the dataframe... such great tool!!! Thank you Jay!!!

Answer (score 3):

I do this from time to time in QGIS:

1. Add an OpenLayers layer (in this case OSM);
2. Set the project projection to the desired coord system (i.e. WGS84 UTM 36S);
3. Create a new temporary shapefile or Spatialite layer (tempWKT here), also set to the correct coord system;
4. Start editing the temp layer and add the desired polygon:

[image]

5. Select the polygon using the selection tool;
6. Edit | Copy Features;
7. Paste into a text editor, giving you the attribute table with the WKT text:

`wkt_geom   id  name
POLYGON((326815 8528822,327693 8520261,332303 8515651,343279 8517626,353597 8528383,342621 8536945,326815 8528822)) 1`

Comment: Interesting! And good to know as there aren't tools to draw graphics in QGIS, so this is a good workaround! Thanks, @Simbamangu!

Comment: I just tried this and it works great - it will do us well when we're using QGIS/PostGIS... thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The Feature info tool of OpenJUMP shows also the WKT of selected features.

[image]

[image]

However, with some scripting it is possible to not only show the WKT but also to embed WKT into something else and more powerful.

Here comes a small OpenJUMP tool that takes the WKT of each feature from a layer and inserts it into Intersects query for Oracle Spatial.

Install OpenJUMP and save the following code as "Show_WKT.bsh" into the directory of Bean tools "\lib\ext\BeanTools".

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.*;
import com.vividsolutions.jump.feature.*;
import com.vividsolutions.jump.workbench.model.*;

    htmlFrame = wc.workbench.frame.outputFrame;
    htmlFrame.createNewDocument();
    htmlFrame.setTitle("WKT Output");
    fc = wc.getLayerNamePanel().getSelectedLayers()[0].getFeatureCollectionWrapper();
    for (Iterator i = fc.getFeatures().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        Feature feature = (Feature) i.next();
        Geometry geometry = feature.getGeometry();
            htmlFrame.addText("SELECT * \n"
            +"FROM ORACLE_TABLE ot \n"
            +"WHERE sdo_anyinteract (ot.geoloc,SDO_GEOMETRY('"
            +geometry
            +"',SRID))='TRUE';"
                );
    }
    wc.workbench.frame.flash(htmlFrame);
    htmlFrame.surface();
}
```

Start OpenJUMP and draw some features and test your new tool. It should be on a list in Customize - Bean Tools.

[image]

Select the tool from the menu and it will create Oracle queries which contain WKT of the features.
[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the default cut'n'copy action in JUMP is to take the feature into the clipboard as WKT. So you can high light a feature, copy, then paste into another app as WKT.

Comment: Right. I edited the answer to show that as a first option. I also edited the script to show an example about how to embed WKT to a complete SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Openlayers have an nice example on generating WKT on the fly for drawn objects.

http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/docs/examples/wkt.html

I know that it is not a desktop version that you ask fore, but it is probably the simplest solution you can find...

Comment: that threw an error in the latest version of firefox... hmmm

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of QGIS has an option to **Create New Temporary Scratch Layer**:

[image]

Choose the geometry type and coordinate system, and the layer is added to the map and an edit session is started.

Draw the feature type you're after (in my case a polygon) and use the identify tool to see the attributes.

Right-click on the 'feature id' node, and choose 'Copy Feature'

[image]

Now in PGAdmin, or even QGIS DB Manager, paste the result:

[image]

And with a little [SQL Spatial](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html) you can turn this into a geometry object:

[image]

(note I've added 4326 as the coordinate system I use, which is also the coordinate system I used to create the temporary scratch layer)

Now you can use this to build a geometry object you can run spatial queries against, for example:

```
with polygon as (

select ST_GeomFromText('
Polygon ((-105.03792611059080286 39.78014782225491786, -105.04818400099962616 39.75856265597848704, -105.02284438556741009 39.75418720873850731, -105.01231287864754904 39.76789982851657612, -105.01364722199988933 39.78389171288461768, -105.03792611059080286 39.78014782225491786))', 4326)
 as geom) 

select
* from public."Schools_Current" as sch
, polygon 
where ST_Intersects(sch.geom, polygon.geom)
```

...which returns the schools that fall into the polygon object I've created...